# how to highlight buttons in extjs when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Today',
    ui:'default-toolbar',
    margin: '10 10 10 10'
},{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Yesterday',
    ui:'default-toolbar',
    margin: '0 10 10 10'

    }
},{
    xtype: 'button',
    text:'Last 7 days',
    ui:'default-toolbar',
    margin: '0 10 10 10'
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Last Month',
    ui:'default-toolbar',
    margin: '0 10 10 10'

}]
```

Comment: after clicking on button the clicked button should be in highlighted state

Comment: Post your code in some fiddle

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qt

Comment: posted sample code in fiddle i want to selected button should be in highlighted state when it is selected that helps user to show which button is selected can you help me out

Comment: Your code is not running.it has errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.Button` have a property `enableToggle` which if set to true will apply `pressedCls` to the button when clicked and remove the `pressedCls` when pressed again.

**Sample Code:**

```js
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'My Button',
        enableToggle: true
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

**For Multiple Button:**
When we need to toggle `pressedCls` between mutiple button.We need to use `toggleGroup` property of button. It will toggle the **pressedCls** among multiple where same `toggleGroup` is given.

**Sample Code:**

```js
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
layout:'vbox',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Today',
        enableToggle: true,
        toggleGroup:'myButtonGroup'
      },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Yesterday',
        enableToggle: true,
        toggleGroup:'myButtonGroup'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Last 7 days',
        enableToggle: true,
        toggleGroup:'myButtonGroup'
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have multiple buttons how can i apply pressedCls to new button and remove pressedCls from previous button instead of clicking on same button again to remove pressedCls. thanks in advance

Comment: thanks it worked for me and i have doubt if i have one more button which is not in "toggleGroup" when clicking on that button how to  set "enableToggle: false"  to the button in "togglegroup" which is selected previously !! any fiddle example will help full to me thanks in advance

Comment: clicking on "new " button which is not in toggle group how to set enableToggle to flase the button like "yesterday " which is clicked previously and  toggled

Comment: Give these 2 lines `Ext.getCmp('xyz').toggle(false);Ext.getCmp('xyz').enableToggle=false;`